# Can anyone tell my why this plnkr can't find my module?

Tags: angularjs

For some reason, angular doesn't known that I have declared an angular module and named it "APP".  http://plnkr.co/edit/TY9uiHBYapkyzxsVn3cg

Am I missing something?

Comment: var app = angular.module("APP", []);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the forked version that is working - and yes you forgot the [] in the:

```
var app = angular.module('APP', []);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/RzT5ptS6miSabO6mO1Qx

Comment: smh...I knew I could count on you guys for a quick sanity check.